# How to push a Yeoman app to a server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to push a project I created using the `Yeoman's angular generator` template to a server.

This is my project -

[image]

This is in my app folder -

[image]

This is the node-modules folder. For some reason, Yeoman has installed several node-modules. I am not using all of these.

[image]

The list goes on. This is just a small snippet of what's in the `node-modules` folder.

In order to push to the server, I am using `grunt build`. This generates a `dist` folder with the following content -

[image].

However when I navigate to my views, (e.g. `reset-password`), I get an error that this file is not available.

I am guessing this is because the `dist` folder doesn't have the `views` folder that the `app` folder does.

My final requirement is I want to push this project to the server, so that it is accessible to anyone. I don't want to push all the node-modules because I am not using them.

UPDATE -

This is the content in dist/scripts/ -

[image]

In the `script.2a4ac124.js` file, all my views are referenced but when I try to navigate to - `file:///Users/proj/Documents/sso/dist/reset-password` I get a file not found error, but when I navigate to file:///Users/proj/Documents/sso/dist/index.html#/ I see the `index` page.

Comment: Can you provide a link to which yeoman generator you used, there is many available.

Comment: @sebastienbarbier This is the generator I am using - https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Comment: Are there any errors when you run grunt build?  It seems like something is stopping your views folder from being copied over.

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run `grunt build`. @RobLouie

Comment: Okay, cool, is grunt caching your html in your scripts file?  Take a look at that scripts file and see if your templates are in there.  If they are everything should be okay and you can simply copy the contents of your dist folder to your sever to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

1. installing node modules is normal - it installs development dependencies, which will be used in the grunt tasks that Yeoman creates. The reason there are so many is because the dev dependencies have their own dependencies that need to be resolved.
2. reset-password navigation error is most likely some build error, though it is difficult to tell just from the description. Yeoman converts the view files into angularJS templateCache and puts them into the concat/uglified js file (usually the app-.js file). First see if they are there. If they aren't, the view files aren't getting build. If they are there, it could be that the templates are incorrectly cached, or it could also be something else totally.
3. To deploy your application, simply copy the contents of dist folder to wherever you are deploying. You don't need the node_modules, since they are only used for performing dev. tasks.

Also,

Your screenshots show a SignUpCtrl.js file at the app root. Yeoman scaffoldings, whichever one you are using, usually aren't designed to have script files at the app root. Try putting it back inside the scripts file first.

Comment: Please look at the `UPDATE` section of my question.